# set animation on listview scrolling in android

Tags: android, listview, animation, scroll

I want to set an animation for a `ListView` for when a user scrolls the `ListView`. I am setting an animation for `ListView` when loading, but I want to set an animation for scrolling.

This is my animation file in eclipse :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";   
    android:duration="900" android:fromXDelta="-100%p" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" 
    android:repeatCount="0" android:repeatMode="reverse" 
    android:fillEnabled="true" android:fillAfter="true" android:toXDelta="0%p" >
</translate>
```

this code is set items to my listview :

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    StructNote item = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_notes, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.fill(this, item, position); return convertView;
}
```

and this is a ActivityMain that set animation to listview

```
ListView lstContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstContent);
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);    
lstContent.setLayoutAnimation(new LayoutAnimationController(animation));
```

Any one can help me??

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="900"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" >
</translate>

Comment: this code is set items to my listview :

  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        StructNote item = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_notes, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.fill(this, item, position);
        return convertView;
    }

Comment: and this is a ActivityMain that set animation to listview :

 ListView lstContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstContent);
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        lstContent.setLayoutAnimation(new LayoutAnimationController(animation));

Comment: You should post your code in the post, not in comments. And you should check out Recyclerview and ItemAnimator

Comment: which type of animation you want to set for scroll???

Comment: type of animation is not important for me , but i make an custom animation ,

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ListView Adapter:**

```
Animation scaleUp;

 public MyAdapter(...) {
           //...
     scaleUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.scale_up_fast);
 }

 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    CardView cv;

    if (convertView == null){
      inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);
    }
    cv = (CardView) convertView.findById(R.id.yourView);//Change this to your view      
    cv.startAnimation(scaleUp);
 }
```

**Animation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" />
</set>
```

Comment: Nice one, but how avoid animation for previously loaded items? I mean while scrolling down, providing animation to list item is OK but it shouldn't animate if I scroll up because those items are already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of way to do this kind of task i'm suggesting you known example, you can create your own animation as well use pre define library for this.
[example 1](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations),[Some listview which have effects extra than the listview widget](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=listview%20)

Comment: Dear friend , what is your suggestion between lots of wat ?

Comment: Lots of way to doing animation in different way as like scale view or parallex background just check on github

Answer (score 0):

well first of all remove `semicolon(;)` from animation xml 
then I have see scroll animation like this app  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nilstechsys.myquotes

and this is a simple code of scroll animation in listview adpter

```
 Animation animation = null;
        animation = new TranslateAnimation(metrics_.widthPixels / 2, 0, 0, 0);
        //animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.your_animation);
        animation.setDuration(400);
        convertView.startAnimation(animation);
        animation = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the best possible solution that i can give to you as per your requirement! Please go through this Adapter once.**

```
 public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

            private int mLastPosition;

            public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> objects) {
                super(context, 0, objects);
            }

            private class ViewHolder{
                public TextView mTextView;
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewHolder holder;

                if (convertView == null) {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
                    holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                holder.mTextView.setText(getItem(position));

                // This tells the view where to start based on the direction of the scroll.
                // If the last position to be loaded is <= the current position, we want
                // the views to start below their ending point (500f further down).
                // Otherwise, we start above the ending point.
                float initialTranslation = (mLastPosition <= position ? 500f : -500f);

                convertView.setTranslationY(initialTranslation);
                convertView.animate()
                        .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1.0f))
                        .translationY(0f)
                        .setDuration(300l)
                        .setListener(null);

                // Keep track of the last position we loaded
                mLastPosition = position;

                return convertView;
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and fabulous animation on listview scrolling**

```
 @Override`
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View converview = view;`
// other coding related to view

    if (animateOrNot) {    //boolean if want to animate
        doCards(converview, i, prevPos);}
       `prevPos=i; //take prevPos as global variable of int
    return converview;
}`



    public static void doCards(View view, int position, int prevPosition) {
    view.setScaleX(0.5f);
    if (position > prevPosition) {
        view.setRotationX(90);
    } else {
        view.setRotationX(-90);
    }
    view.animate().rotationX(0).scaleX(1.0f).start();
}
```