# Make listview use slow scrolling

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to make the listview scrolling animation slower than normal. I tried setting fast Scroll to false on the listview. But it would be preferable to make it even slower

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Yes, I just googeled your question and I can confirm it's possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35697038/2993413 check if it's useful for you

Comment: @A.Wolf thanks alot for this, it works